# Why saliva comes out of my mouth during sleeping?

Tags: saliva

Why saliva comes out of my mouth during sleeping ? Usually saliva does not disturbs me but, I am disturbed due do to saliva during sleeping.

Comment: Are there any people around you while you sleep? Have you ever considered a video camera?

Comment: I sleep with all my family members and I have not used video camera so far for analyzing my situation.